# Add a calculated result with multiple columns to Pandas DataFrame with MultiIndex columns

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a DataFrame like so:

```
In [10]: df.head()
Out[10]: 
      sand              silt              clay             rho_b  ...      n  \
        5     25    60    5     25    60    5     25    60    5   ...     60   
STID                                                              ...          
ACME  73.0  60.3  52.5  19.7  23.9  25.9   7.2  15.7  21.5  1.27  ...   1.32   
ADAX  61.1  51.1  47.6  22.0  25.4  24.6  16.9  23.5  27.8  1.01  ...   1.25   
ALTU  23.8  17.8  14.3  40.0  45.2  40.9  36.2  37.0  44.8  1.57  ...   1.18   
ALV2  33.3  21.2  19.8  31.4  29.7  29.8  35.3  49.1  50.5  1.66  ...   1.20   
ANT2  55.6  57.5  47.7  34.9  31.1  26.8   9.4  11.3  25.5  1.49  ...   1.29
```

So for every STID (e.g. ACME, ADAX, ALTU), there's some property (e.g. sand, silt, clay) defined at three depths (5, 25, 60).

This structure makes it really easy to do per-depth calculations at each STID, e.g.:

```
In [12]: (df['sand'] + df['silt']).head()
Out[12]: 
        5     25    60
STID                  
ACME  92.7  84.2  78.4
ADAX  83.1  76.5  72.2
ALTU  63.8  63.0  55.2
ALV2  64.7  50.9  49.6
ANT2  90.5  88.6  74.5
```

How can I neatly incorporate a calculated result back in to the DataFrame? For example, if I wanted to call the result of the above calculation `'notclay'`:

```
In [13]: df['notclay'] = df['sand'] + df['silt']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-a30bd9ba99c3> in <module>()
----> 1 df['notclay'] = df['sand'] + df['silt']

<snip>

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1
```

Three columns are expected to be defined for each column in the result, not just the one `'notclay'` column.

I do have a solution using strict assignments, but I'm not very satisfied with it:

```
In [21]: df[[('notclay', 5), ('notclay', 25), ('notclay', 60)]] = df['sand'] + df['silt']

In [22]: df['notclay'].head()
Out[22]: 
        5     25    60
STID                  
ACME  92.7  84.2  78.4
ADAX  83.1  76.5  72.2
ALTU  63.8  63.0  55.2
ALV2  64.7  50.9  49.6
ANT2  90.5  88.6  74.5
```

I have many other calculations to do similar to this one, and using a  strict assignment every time seems tedious. I'm guessing there's a better/"right" way to do this. I think [add a field in pandas dataframe with MultiIndex columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405544/add-a-field-in-pandas-dataframe-with-multiindex-columns) might contain the answer, but I don't very well understand the solutions (or even what a Panel is and if it can help me).

Edit: Something I tried that *doesn't* work, prepending a category using concat:

```
In [36]: concat([df['sand'] + df['silt']], axis=1, keys=['notclay']).head()
Out[36]: 
     notclay            
          5     25    60
STID                    
ACME    92.7  84.2  78.4
ADAX    83.1  76.5  72.2
ALTU    63.8  63.0  55.2
ALV2    64.7  50.9  49.6
ANT2    90.5  88.6  74.5

In [37]: df['notclay'] = concat([df['sand'] + df['silt']], axis=1, keys=['notclay'])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<snip>

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1
```

Same `ValueError` raised as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your taste, this may be a nicer way to do it still using concat:

```
In [53]: df
Out[53]: 
       blah                           foo                    
          1         2         3         1         2         3
a  0.351045  0.044654  0.855627  0.839725  0.675183  0.325324
b  0.610374  0.394499  0.924708  0.924303  0.404475  0.885368
c  0.116418  0.487866  0.190669  0.283535  0.862869  0.346477
d  0.771014  0.204143  0.143449  0.848520  0.887373  0.220083
e  0.103268  0.306820  0.277125  0.627272  0.631019  0.386406

In [54]: newdf
Out[54]: 
          1         2         3
a  0.433377  0.806679  0.976298
b  0.593683  0.217415  0.086565
c  0.716244  0.908777  0.180252
d  0.031942  0.074283  0.745019
e  0.651517  0.393569  0.861616

In [56]: newdf.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['bar'], newdf.columns])

In [57]: pd.concat([df, newdf], axis=1)
Out[57]: 
       blah                           foo                           bar  \
          1         2         3         1         2         3         1   
a  0.351045  0.044654  0.855627  0.839725  0.675183  0.325324  0.433377   
b  0.610374  0.394499  0.924708  0.924303  0.404475  0.885368  0.593683   
c  0.116418  0.487866  0.190669  0.283535  0.862869  0.346477  0.716244   
d  0.771014  0.204143  0.143449  0.848520  0.887373  0.220083  0.031942   
e  0.103268  0.306820  0.277125  0.627272  0.631019  0.386406  0.651517   


          2         3  
a  0.806679  0.976298  
b  0.217415  0.086565  
c  0.908777  0.180252  
d  0.074283  0.745019  
e  0.393569  0.861616
```

In order to store this into the original dataframe, you can simply assign  to it in the last line:

```
In [58]: df = pd.concat([df, newdf], axis=1)
```

Comment: Still seems a little bulky, but definitely easier to automate `pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[var_name], newdf.columns])`. I'll probably accept this unless someone else wants to chime in soon.